# Mask image in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im trying to change a mask to an image in a html5 canvas when the mouse enters the canvas.
When the mouse enters the canvas i draw a shape thats gonna act as a mask. It draws as i want but it wont mask the image.

The function that draws the mask is `drawLine();`
What is wrong here?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');
var mY;
var mX;

img.onload = function () {
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(160, 600);
    context.rect(0, 0, 160, 600);
    context.closePath();
    context.clip();
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
};

img.src = "http://placekitten.com/160/600";

canvas.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    var message = mousePos.y + ', ' + mousePos.x; 
    mY = mousePos.y;
    mX = mousePos.x;
   drawLine();
}, false);

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

function drawLine() {

    if(mX > 80) {
        context.restore();
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(000,000,000)";
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(160, mY);
        context.lineTo(0,mY+setCutAngle());
        context.lineTo(0,600);
        context.lineTo(160,600);
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
    } else {

    }
    context.stroke();
}

function setCutAngle() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 10;
}
```

Comment: The shape gets drawn but it wont mask. Why oh why?

Comment: It works like when you enter the mouse on it a line gets drawn from the first position that the mouse get in Y-axis and then it draws a line from that position straight over to the other side of the div. Everyting below that line should act like a mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0sjdnvq0/8/) Updated so image loads at the start.
I believe your main problem was caused by not clearing the canvas. Thus your clip would not show

Updated JSFIDDLE to match your code. Remove that logic from your load event. It should only happen on your drawevent. You are also not clearling or clipping your image in the draw event.

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');
var mY;
var mX;

img.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};

img.src = "http://placekitten.com/160/600";

canvas.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    var message = mousePos.y + ', ' + mousePos.x; 
    mY = mousePos.y;
    mX = mousePos.x;
    drawLine();
}, false);

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

function drawLine() {
     context.save();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if(mX > 80) {
        context.restore();
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(000,000,000)";
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(160, mY);
        context.lineTo(0,mY+setCutAngle());
        context.lineTo(0,600);
        context.lineTo(160,600);
        context.clip();
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        context.closePath();
    } else {

    }
    context.stroke()
}

function setCutAngle() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 10;
}
```

Comment: The mask is supposed to redraw on every mouseenter. And it does. The thing is just that it dont act as a mask. it just gets a fill-color.

Comment: Thanks! But i actually want it on mouseenter. Why does it not append the mask? only a color. What i want to do is to cut the image of.

Comment: Thanks! Almost. The image should be visible from start. When on mouse enter it should clip/mask the image from the current Y-position of the mouse. Clipping from the Y-pos and down to the bottom. This should happen on every mouse enter. (if there is something left to clip/mask)

Comment: Updated so the image is visible at the start

Comment: I made a fiddle of what i got. http://jsfiddle.net/0sjdnvq0/

Should work like this, but the black rect should be a mask.

Comment: you use the fill method when you want to clip. That is why you are getting the black rect. Updated my fiddle to match what you are doing and it works fine for me

Comment: Thanks! Thats better. bit it seems like its reversed? its supposed to clip from where you enter the mouse and to the bottom. not up to the top.

Comment: Well for that you would have to play around with your shape to what ever coordinates you desire to mask. Fill it in black first so you can better where what the shape is creating. It will mask out only the area of the shape.

But I think this answers your question on why it was not masking